# Change Product Home Page layout

Tags: configuration, record-home-page

I need to change Product home page layout in order to hide Price books related section. Is it possible to do it?[image]

Comment: [Home Page Layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=designing_home_page_layouts.htm&type=0)

Comment: I don't know whether you got my question. I want to customize PRODUCT home page layout and not the HOME tab page layout.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Build| Customise| Products| Page Layout` you can customize the view of the page.

All Standard objects' page layout can be customized under that tab if you have the required permissions.

Note : hiding a field in page layout will hide it from all users, so it's better to use [field level security.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_fls.htm&language=en_US&type=0)